# Tags for resume and cv

Tags: discussion, tagging

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9sum%C3%A9) states the following:

> A résumé [...] is a document used by persons to present their backgrounds and skills. Résumés can be used for a variety of reasons, but most often they are used to secure new employment. A typical résumé contains a "summary" of relevant job experience and education, as its French origin [...] implies. The résumé is usually one of the first items, along with a cover letter and sometimes an application for employment, which a potential employer sees regarding the job seeker and is typically used to screen applicants, often followed by an interview. The curriculum vitae (CV) used for academic purposes in the UK (and in other European countries) is more akin to the résumé — a shorter, summary version of one's education and experience — than to the longer and more detailed c.v. that is expected in U.S. academic circles. Generally, the résumé is substantially shorter than a CV in English Canada, the U.S. and Australia.

---

We currently have just 5 questions tagged [cv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cv?sort=newest&pageSize=50), but 256 tagged [resume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume). The tag info for resume reads:

> {resume} is about creating résumés and CVs with (La)TeX.

Now my question is: Do we keep on retagging cv question or just alias `cv` to be `resume`? Questions tagged `cv` will keep on coming.

Comment: I would say that a CV has more content than a resume, but the typesetting is quite similar, so in that sense [tag:cv] could be an alias

Comment: That's what happens when you use Latin to sound posh.

Answer (score 13):

In most cases a résumé is (much) shorter than a C.V, most times restricted to some personal information, education and job experience.

A C.V. contains more information, much more personal data and interests, so [cv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cv) would be the larger set actually compared to the less informational [resume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume).

The important thing is (as Johannes stated already by citing Wikipedia) that there's no general definition what belongs to a Resume and which (more) contents build up a C.V. There are (huge) differences in the concept of Resume/C.V. between U.S. and Europe for example.

The typesetting issues however (Lists, tables, header etc.) are pretty the same, so we can say that [cv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cv) can be made an alias [resume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume).

Comment: What are the large differences?